# R: how to insert hyperlinks for the dots in a plot? the plot is created with 'grid' and placed in a PDF

Tags: r, pdf, r-grid

I want to create a plot with some dots on it, and there are some info associated with those dots, however, the amount of info is too large to display on the plot. So I want to enable the audience to click the dots to retrieve the info from the web (like a public database). The plot is created with 'grid' system in R, and placed in a PDF.

Of course there are other workarounds, but just to be user-friendly, how to create such a PDF?

Thank you!

update 11/26/2013
I should be clear that I want to do this task AUTOMATICALLY with some scripts written in R (or any other language that could be readily implemented).

Comment: I'm quite sure that kind of interactivity is not possible / hard to do in a pdf file. This sounds more like a job for a web application, e.g. written using Shiny or D3.js.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done afterwards in adobe acrobat.  Simply go into tools and select the link tool.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it automatically, preferably with a R script.